# Change TreeViewItem Color by property of model

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to change the color of a TreeViewItem if the Status property has a specific value, but idk how. Can anyone please help me? Sorry for bad english :(
Here is my Code:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ConstructionSites}">
    <Label Content="{Binding DisplayableInfos}"/>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Test}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

I think it works like this, but it doesn't.
Thank you for your help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Label.Foreground` has a default value set in its default `Style`. Since this property is explicitly set, it won't inherit the `Foreground` value of its parent.

`TextBlock` has not set an explicit `Foreground` and therefore will inherit the `Foreground` of its parent.

The apparent solution is to replace the `Label` with a `TextBlock`. It's generally recommended to use a lightweight `TextBlock` instead of the heavier `Label`. Since `Label` is a `Control`, it offers features like accelerator keys (aka access keys) or a `ControlTemplate` and therefore the deeper visual tree which may containg a `Border` etc. The deeper visual tree also makes the `Label` heavy compared to the `TextBlock`, which is a plain `FrameworkElement` (and therefore has no child tree or a depth of '0'). If you don't need any of this always prefer the `TextBlock`:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ConstructionSites}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayableInfos}"/>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Test}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```